# Is every sigma-algebra generated by some topology?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Well, my question is precisely what the title says: Is every sigma-algebra on a set $X$ generated by some topology on $X$? Actually,I am unable to either prove or create a counterexample, but I have a strong feeling, that in case the answer turns out to be in the affirmitive, its proof must involve the *Axiom of Choice*.

Comment: The question has been discussed here:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87838/is-every-sigma-algebra-the-borel-algebra-of-a-topology

Comment: See also: http://mathoverflow.net/a/70152/22971